# django-tastypie How to PUT a datetime field with "now" value

Tags: django, rest, tastypie

I've set up a RESTfull interface with django-tastypie.

All is going well so far, BUT i can't find a way to POST/PUT/PATCH a datetime field to NOW (as in SQL) to use server's current time, instead of the client one.

Maybe im doing it wrong, I have a resource with some fields and I want users to be able to validate or unvalidate it. So i've added "validated_at" in my model. Sending string "2012-01-01T15:43:00" works, but if I set to "Now", an error is returned because the date is not correctly formatted.

Is there a way to do that? Thanks!

Comment: It should be possible if you call 'hydrate_datetimefield' and inside check if it is 'Now' set it to datetime.now and than super().hydrate_datefield.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've updated with the code. I didnt manage to call super().. but it seams to work. I think the model DateTime do the rest of the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the best code i wrote so far... but it does the trick.

```
def hydrate_validate_at(self, bundle):
    validate_at = bundle.data.get("validate_at", None)
    if validate_at == "None":
        bundle.data["validate_at"] = None
    elif validate_at == "Now":
        bundle.data["validate_at"] = datetime.now()
    return bundle
```